# RxJS 4.0.1 - subscribe to button clicks not working (plain js)

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm trying to learn RP by writing some small applications. It seems I'm missing something very basic here.

I'm trying to listen to button clicks with good old vanilla js. No jQuery, no amber, just plain js. **RxJS version is 4.0.1**.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#button');
var buttonClickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');

var buttonClick = buttonClickStream.subscribe(
  function(i){console.log("read")},
  function(e){console.log(e)},
  function(){console.log("done")}
);
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button">read</button>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.1/rx.all.js"></script>
```

I'm quite confused as this seemed pretty straigh forward to me and in [this (quite good) tutorial](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) it's pretty much the same.

Am I missing something? Is this a *cold vs hot* issue? Calling `buttonClick.onNext()` manually produces the output whereas clicking the button doesn't. Already tried with `document` instead of `button` and `mousedown`instead of `click`. Using latest ff (41 I guess).

The [official docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromevent.md) don't mention plain javascript.

**TL;DR**: RxJS, listen to button click, plain javascript, not working

Comment: Looks like this is bug. Take a look on issue which I reported https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/962

Comment: @xgrommx is right, there is a bug in the current version (4.0.1). There should be a fix in soon. But for the time being you should be able to just switch back to 4.0.0.

Comment: Great, hours wasted again :/ Thanks for your comment. If you post it as an answer I'll gladly accept it and rephrase my question to put emphasis on this specific version.

Comment: Glad I saw this, as I was trying the Drag'n'Drop example which wasn't working either. Pointing to CDN's 4.0.0 version fixed that, indeed.

Comment: Seems like 4.0.2 is already available: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/rxjs